# Calculate tableHeaderView height with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, tableheader

This is my xib File:

[image]

As you can see i have a `UITableView` with a `tableHeaderView` (orange Color)! Everything is shown correct during runtime, except when the title Label have more than one Line, than the `UILabel` get´s cut off with the typically "..". I already changed the `numberOfLines` to 0!

I recognized the Problem is the Height of the whole tableHeaderView! This is how i calculated the Height in Code:

```
[self.headerView setNeedsLayout];
[self.headerView layoutIfNeeded];

CGFloat height = [self.headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + self.headerView.frame.origin.y;

CGRect headerFrame = self.headerView.frame;
headerFrame.size.height = height;
self.headerView.frame = headerFrame;

[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
```

But during runtime the tableHeaderView is too small to show 2 or 3 or 4... Lines of the title Label. What could be the Problem?

Comment: Did you set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for the label? As described here: http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying too hard to fit you content into the tableview header, which was designed to contain relatively small **static** content.

Assuming what you want is your tableview to stay at the bottom of the orange view, and the orange view to scroll with the tableview (ie. not stay at the top of the screen at all time), I would add a scroll view parent of both the orange view and the tableview, and disable the tableview scroll capability.

This means however to exchange your UITableViewController for a UIViewController.

eg.

```
-- UIScrollView
  |
  -- UIView (orange view)
  | |
  | -- subview 1
  | -- subview 2
  | -- etc.
  |
  -- UITableView (scrollEnabled = NO)
```

With AutoLayout, you can make the orange view resize automatically to fit its content, which will "push" the UITableView down.
When the user swipe vertically, the root scrollview will catch the events, and scroll the whole (orangeView + tableView) accordingly, resulting in the same effect as if the orange view was the table view header.

Comment: Sounds like a good Idea, but what will happen with the reusable Cells of the UITableView when i set scrollEnabled to NO and only the "Main ScrollView" scrolls? Is the "reusable Part" still working?

Comment: Ah right. Take a look at [OLEContainerScrollView](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/scrollviews-inside-scrollviews/) that should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Setting tableHeaderView height dynamically

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {

        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

post: https://newbedev.com/setting-tableheaderview-height-dynamically